# Pan Camera moving only in one direction not in all 4 as it should

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

Why in following code in unity is the X coordinate of vector3 move always 0?
Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint method returns X -component always as 0, even though Input.mounsPosition provides X!=0.

```
private void Pan() {

  // save initial position of mouse whenn RMB pressed for first time
  if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)) {
    mouseWorldPosStart = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
  }

  // calculate distance between initial mouse position and current mouse position
  if (Input.GetMouseButton(1)) {
    var newMousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

    Vector3 mouseWorldPosDiff = mouseWorldPosStart - newMousePosition;
    Debug.Log("Initial position: " + mouseWorldPosStart + " Delta = " + mouseWorldPosDiff + " New Position: " + newMousePosition);
    //move the camere by the distance
    transform.position += mouseWorldPosDiff;
  }
}
```

The goal is to write code for Camera Pan function.

Comment: `ScreenToWorldPoint` returns a position in 3D space depending on the camera position, rotation, perspective/orthographic projection matrix etc .... What exactly is the expected behavior you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to provide camera Pan funktion, so it means: when the right mouse button is pressed and dragging mouse to right camera should be moving left and so on in 4 directions.

Comment: ...at the moment camera is moving up only

Comment: So this is attached to the camera itself right?  And shall it be more like dragging -> you press the mouse and then basically drag the scene ... or shall it be more like kinda joystick where you move the camera in the direction the cursor has from the center of the screen -> the closer to the screen border the faster the movement?

Comment: exactly, dragging(not rotating) the camera so that the user can preview the 3d Model by pressing RMB and dragging the mouse.
 Rotating the camera with the mouse (like in the second part of Your Question) is already done - uff :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue will be that while you move the camera the `ScreenToWorldPoint` already returns a new value even without moving the cursor further.

You rather need to store the original point and use a delta to move the camera. I think maybe something like e.g.

```
// in general cache the reference
[SerializeField] private Camera camera;

// world space point where we started to pan 
private Vector3 panStart;
private Vector3 initialPosition;

private void Awake()
{
    if(!camera) camera = Camera.main;
}

void Update ()
{
    // only true the first frame of the panning 
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
    {
        initialPosition = camera.transform.position;
        panStart = camera.transform.InverseTransformPoint(camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
    {
        var pan = panStart - camera.transform.InverseTransformPoint(camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));
        camera.transform.position = initialPosition + camera.transform.TransformVector(pan);
    }
}
```

the trick here is that we use the local space to calculate the pan then convert it back into global space in order to add this delta to the initial world space position. This way the movement of the camera itself won't affect the `ScreenToWorldPoint` delta directly

Comment: thanks! I aaplied Your Idea, and the problem wit X coordinate repeats: Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) reutrns the cordinates of camera while moveing mouse and delte stays 0.

Comment: PS. this is a 3D game object.